# Sencha + phone gap code in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I am creating sencha + phone gap app it successfully run on iphone and android  but it not working in windows phone 7 . any one help me how can i implement sencha code in windows phone 7

Comment: Can you define "not working"?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Sencha Touch didn't officially support Windows Phone until Windows Phone 8.

Unfortunately the browser in Windows Phone 7 devices just doesn't support modern enough versions of HTML and CSS to work with ST.